# How do I remove Google Apps Script? It was downloaded by mistake

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I remove Google Apps Script from my Google Drive?  It was downloaded by mistake.  Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't download apps script, you subscribe to it, as so you can unsubscribe in Drive -> Setting -> Google Apps Script -> Options -> Disconect from Drive.

If you have the chrome apps on the task bar on windows, just open it, right click on Apps Script then remove.

That beeing said, there's no reason to remove it other than having less one icon on the task bar.